# ERROR in ./src/app.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-present-env'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

When I run command 'npm run build', I get this error:

> ERROR in ./src/app.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module
>   '@babel/preset-present-env' from 'F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1'
>       at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:89:15)
>       at resolveStandardizedName (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
>       at resolvePreset (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
>       at loadPreset (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
>       at createDescriptor (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
>       at F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
>       at Array.map ()
>       at createDescriptors (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
>       at createPresetDescriptors (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
>       at presets (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19)
>       at mergeChainOpts (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
>       at F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at buildRootChain (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:90:27)
>       at buildRootChain.next ()
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:95:62)
>       at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next ()
>       at Function. (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:120:25)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at evaluateSync (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\gensync\index.js:244:28)
>       at Function.sync (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\gensync\index.js:84:14)
>       at Object. (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\index.js:41:61)
>       at Object. (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:151:26)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:103)
>       at _next (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:194)
>       at F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:364
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object. (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:97)
>       at Object._loader (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:231:18)
>       at Object.loader (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:64:18)
>       at Object. (F:\Project\frontend-project-lvl1\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:12)

My config is:
**package.json**

```
{

  "name": "frontend-project-lvl1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/an-palna/frontend-project-lvl1.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/an-palna/frontend-project-lvl1/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/an-palna/frontend-project-lvl1#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
        presets: [
                ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]
              ]        
              }
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ]
};
```

**babel.config**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/present-env', {
      targets: {
        node: 'current',
        firefox: '60',
        chrome: '67',
        safari: '11.1',
      },
    }],
  ],
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `['@babel/present-env'`, { to `['@babel/preset-env'`, in your **babel.config**